# jQuery autocomplete with IF statements

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, sql, autocomplete

Hopefully an easy question, I'm using jQuery autocomplete which is working fine and is returning the values based on a SQL query where `LIKE $querystring`.

Now I want to add an additional dropdown list on my ASPX page that will run a different SQL query based on what is selected which will get passed through to the `Search.php` at the same time the user is typing in the autocomplete field.

So to put it simply I want to use the dropdown list to search different rows in my SQL DB and return autocomplete results based on that row. Can someone help me from the ASPX side and also how to read the value from the PHP side.

ASPX code is like this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Thanks

Comment: You are using both ASPX and PHP server-side?? Uh... whuuuut?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!

From the aspx side:
There are multiple ways that you do that, but I prefer [TypeAhead](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead) of Bootstrap.

Here the add the data-provide attribute

You may use

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="ucUserSearch" runat="server" class="typeahead" 
   data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Enter text" autocomplete="off" 
    data-items="4" />
```

Then from the server side you pass the data from the search.php using json stringified object.

Make an ajax call with the url as search.php and attach the data-source to the 
textbox.

Here is a sample code that I used in one of my recent projects.I mean You can write a
similar code to achieve the results.

Here we had used the typeahead class so lets select that element through Jquery

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {

                return $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: '{ "prefixText": "' + query + '" }',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //On Success lets return the values
                        //Please make sure to check how the json data is 
                         //coming I had to use data.d in my case
                        var jsonData = FetchedData(data.d);
                        return process(jsonData);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("Failure");
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("There seems to be an error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });


function FetchedData(data) {
            return data;
        }
```

Cheers!!!

Note: Here I have made use of bootstrap.css,jquery, and bootstrap.min.js files, Please make
sure to include these